# How to get following output in sql pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have follwing data in a table

```
id  userid  meta_type   meta_data
89  245 document    1564568647_Penguins.jpg
92  245 brochure    1564568700_Desert.jpg
93  298 profile_vistor  203.109.68.198
```

I need to convert to this way using query

```
id  userid document                brouchure                profile_vistor
89  245    1564568647_Penguins.jpg 1564568700_Desert.jpg    NULL
93  298    NULL                    NULL                     203.109.68.198
```

I have tried following query but not getting above output.

```
   SELECT *
    FROM
      (SELECT id,userid,meta_type FROM dbo.[user_meta_new]
      ) AS t PIVOT ( max(id)
              FOR meta_type IN(document,brochure,profile_vistor,portfolio)) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select min(id), userid,
       max(case when meta_type = 'document' then meta_data end) as document,
       max(case when meta_type = 'brochure' then meta_data end) as brochure,
       max(case when meta_type = 'profile_vistor' then meta_data end) as profile_vistor
from t
group by userid;
```